# How to correctly return the path to an image from the ternary operator (and display it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ternary-operator

I am new to rails.

I am trying to implement the following method in my User model

```
  def avatar_to_load
      self.picture ? self.picture.url : image_path("logo.png")
  end
```

Which if the User has a picture, then it will display the picture, if not, it will display the "logo.png", the path of which is app/assets/images/logo.png

I am very new to rails so I understand this is likely to be very simple.

The output is via

```
    <%= image_tag user.avatar_to_load %>
```

This works fine

```
    <%= image_tag user.image_path("logo.png") %>
```

So I am unsure why this isn't returning from the method.

Comment: Isn't image_path a view helper? This should be reflected by an error in your logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like that

```
<%= image_tag (user.picture.present? ? user.picture.url : "logo.png") %>
```

Or

```
<%= image_tag (user.picture.present? ? user.picture.url : "logo.png"), :style => "width: 400px; height: 200px;" %>
```

Comment: One thing....is it possible to apply the size option to this code? Does the inclusion of the ternary operator prevent options being added?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use image_path in a model you need to call `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("logo.png");`

Or make an helper instead of a class method.

```
module UserHelper
  def avatar_to_load(user)
      user.picture ? user.picture.url : image_path("logo.png")
  end
end
```

And call it in your views : `<%= avatar_to_load(@user) %>`

Answer (score 0):

Add `self.` before image_path()?

```
  def avatar_to_load
      self.picture ? self.picture.url : self.image_path("logo.png")
  end
```